# BotFramework: PrivateConversationData or UserData becomes empty

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

In `MessagesController.cs`, following code is executed in `Post` method,

```
if (activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("code:"))
{
    var stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
    var botData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
    var token = botData.GetProperty<string>("AccessToken");

    BotUserModel botUser = CreateNewUser(token);

    var privateData = await stateClient.BotState.GetPrivateConversationDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id);
    privateData.SetProperty<BotUserModel>("botUser", botUser);
}
else 
{
     await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new LuisDialog());
}
```

This is saving botUser into **PrivateConversationData** dictionary

Inside the LUIS Dialog,

```
[LuisIntent("DoSomething")]
public async Task DoSomething(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    BotUserModel botUser;
    context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<BotUserModel>("botUser", out botUser);             

   // Just to test
   context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<BotUserModel>("TestValue", new BotUserModel());
}
```

Here, I'm getting an exception **KeyNotFoundException:botUser**

BotUserModel is marked `[Serializable]` and has few public properties - all with get/set. I checked the IBotBag (i.e. PrivateConversationData) and its empty

```
 [LuisIntent("DoSomethingNew")]
 public async Task DoSomethingNew(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
 {
      // Assuming DoSomething intent is invoked first        
      BotUserModel botUser;
      context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<BotUserModel>("TestValue", out botUser);             
      // Here, no exception!
 }
```

Now, here I get the value of TestValue set in LUIS Dialog in `DoSomething` method.

So essentially, any data set to PrivateConversationData or UserData inside LUIS Intent is accessible by other LUIS intents; whereas, data set in MessageController.cs (before LUIS is called) is not accessible within LUIS.

Tried with `UserData` as well.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to set the private data store back into the state client. This should make it work.

```
var privateData = await stateClient.BotState.GetPrivateConversationDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id);
privateData.SetProperty<BotUserModel>("botUser", botUser);
await stateClient.BotState.SetPrivateConversationDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id, privateData);
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html) on the state client.

Comment: Well spotted.. Missed that one line!